# UIAppearance Proxy interoperation with Storyboards

Tags: ios, uikit, uistoryboard, uiappearance

If I set a property of a `UIView` in a storyboard, should this override the default that is provided by an [appearance proxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/)?

My application has `[UIToolbar.appearance setBarTintColor: UIColor.myCustomColour]`. This works as expected.

I have a specific `UIToolbar` that needs a different `barTint`. I've set this in the storyboard editor: instead of `Default`, the toolbar uses a grey colour. However, this colour seems to be ignored at run time and the toolbar gets the global colour instead.

Comment: Just found this question in 2019 and thought it was a great one so tried to give it an upvote because it needs an answer. Apparently I asked it. Who knew?!